# AVAudioUnitSampler loading delay issue in iOS 11 but not iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios11, avaudioengine

Running on iOS 10 I am able to load a sample from file into an AVAudioUnitSampler on demand and it plays correctly.
However when I run the same code on iOS 11 the audio doesn't play. In order to get it to work I have to preload the audio.

Has something changed in iOS 11 that causes this to no longer work?

The is designed to play from a selection of about to 100 samples, some of them longer than others, so I can't load them all into memory in advance and thus need to load on demand.

I've tried this on iOS 11, 11.0.1 and 11.0.2.

Any suggestions?

This is my initial version (works on iOS 10 but not iOS 11):

```
var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!  
var mixer:AVAudioMixerNode!  
var sampler:AVAudioUnitSampler!  

override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()  
    mixer = audioEngine.mainMixerNode  
    mixer.volume = 1.0  

    do {  
        try audioEngine.start()  
    } catch {  
        print(error)  
    }  

    sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()  

    audioEngine.attach(sampler)  
    audioEngine.connect(sampler, to: mixer, format: nil)  
} 

@IBAction func audio1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {  
   if let audioPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a73", withExtension: "wav") {  
        do {  
            try sampler.loadAudioFiles(at: [audioPath])  
            sampler.startNote(60, withVelocity: 127, onChannel: 0)  
        } catch {  
            print(error.localizedDescription)  
        }  
    } else {  
        print("Failed to find audio file")  
    }  

}
```

The following works on iOS 11:

```
var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!  
var mixer:AVAudioMixerNode!  
var sampler:AVAudioUnitSampler!  

override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()  
    mixer = audioEngine.mainMixerNode  
    mixer.volume = 1.0  

    do {  
        try audioEngine.start()  
    } catch {  
        print(error)  
    }  

    sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()  

    audioEngine.attach(sampler)  
    audioEngine.connect(sampler, to: mixer, format: nil)  

    if let audioPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a73", withExtension: "wav") {  
        do {  
            try sampler.loadAudioFiles(at: [audioPath])  
        } catch {  
            print(error.localizedDescription)  
        }  
    } else {  
        print("Failed to find audio file")  
    }  
}

@IBAction func audio1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {  
    sampler.startNote(60, withVelocity: 127, onChannel: 0)  
}
```

Comment: AVAudioEngine.start() invokes the prepare() method it it has not already been called.

Comment: @matt I’ve just watched the video thanks but didn’t see anything that addresses the issue I have.